# Silence vroom::vroom?

Tags: r, csv, verbosity

`vroom::vroom()` gives a quite verbose `message` to console. For example:

```
> my_data = vroom::vroom("my_data.csv")

## Rows: 6,608                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
## Columns: 9
## Delimiter: ";"
## chr  [2]: panel_rev, pcb_rev
## dbl  [5]: panel_id, panel_type, work_order_lot_id, location_id, panel_number
## dttm [2]: marking_dt, created_dt
## 
## Use `spec()` to retrieve the guessed column specification
## Pass a specification to the `col_types` argument to quiet this message
```

Is there a way to silence it other than `my_data = suppressMessages(vroom::vroom("my_data.csv"))` or is this the preferred way?

Comment: currently don't see any way to avoid running the line `show_spec_summary(out, locale = locale)` in `vroom`, it should be obvious that users don't want to see this. still waiting on the `tidyverse` package `do_all_my_thinking_for_me`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if these are new features since this question was answered, but setting `progress = FALSE` and the `col_types = cols()` can be used to silence `vroom::vroom` completely. The `col_types = cols()` is common across *most* `tidyverse` data loading functions:

```
my_data <- vroom::vroom("my_data.csv", progress = FALSE, col_types = cols())
```

Answer (score 3):

More recent versions show that you can silent vroom with `show_col_types=FALSE`.

```r
my_data = vroom::vroom("my_data.csv", show_col_types=FALSE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your best option so far is to suppress messages and suppress the progress bar as follows:

1. Suppress the progress bar by setting this environment variable

   ```
   Sys.setenv("VROOM_SHOW_PROGRESS"="false")
   ```
2. Suppress the messages with:

   ```
   suppressMessages(vroom("myfile"))
   ```

Comment: Did not work in Vroom 1.5.7. Newer version do not seem to support it in this way. IT affects how [`vroom_progress()`](https://vroom.r-lib.org/reference/vroom_progress.html) works but probably not the output generated by `vroom()`.